# Which Salesforce scanner tool can I use to scan Chrome Extension(built on Angular utilizing Salesforce APIs)?

Tags: salesforcedx, appexchange, isv, security-review, security-scanner

We have a Chrome Extension built upon Angular utilizing Salesforce APIs, now We want to publish it on APP Exchange, so we have to upload a scanner report, which scanner tool can we use?

I tried using **OWASP ZAP**, It asks for a **URL to Attack** and here I am using Local Host as URL, I am not sure if Salesforce allows scanner reports generated for Local Host.

pls help

Answer (score 0):

Static Code analysis is done using tools like Checkmarx which has support for different languages including javascript. Along with that Chimera is also used. See [Salesforce Scanner](https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/) and [Checkmarx](https://checkmarx.com/) . You can also schedule office hours with the appexchange team to discuss your issues related to scanning.